# How do I escape from the mode of giving follower commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Game: The elder srolls V - Skyrim with all official patches

Yesterday I asked my follower in the game to do something. I forgot how this happened, but finally I found I am not able to escape to the normal mode any more!

attempts:

1. Escape key - shows the normal system menu and back to command mode
2. Tab key - show the "skill - magic - item - map" cross and back to command mode
3. Fast travel to locations - fine, but still in command mode
4. Save game, exit to desktop, and start with continue - in command mode
5. Ask follower to depart - he is gone, but the cursor is still in command mode, and I cannot even open a door!

and finally this was resolved by loading an earlier saved game.

Did any one have this problem before? How to resolve this issue? I mean, escape from command mode without lost recent activities.

**Additional**

I here list which mods I have installed

- A Quality World Map
- ApachiiSkyHair v1.5 full
- Calierntes Beautiful Bodies CBBE
- Evil Lair of Hydra
- HDT HighHeels System 0.5
- Lockpick Pro Cheat
- RaceMenu
- SkyUI
- Sweet and Sexy Lingerie shop CBBE

Unfortunately I didn't backup the problematic saved game so it might or might not be able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Is this a question? It sort'a looks like you already answered it. **How to resolve it?** well, you stated that **This was finally resolved by loading an earlier saved game**.

Comment: NO... loading an earlier saved game is not a good solution. What if you didn't saved before? What if you have something you don't want to lost?

Comment: I have never met this problem, but I guess you should start by trying to recreate the issue with and without the mods.
If you do get to the "check the mods" phase I'd start with Evil lair of hydra, LockPick Pro and LingerieShop, for the simple reason that I don't have those :) This seems rather system-specific though, good luck finding out the reason!

Answer (score 2):

The `ESC` key always works for me, as does the space bar. I suspect any key other than a movement, camera, or activate key will work. I've been watching some Let's Play videos where the player ends command mode by looking at the follower again and talking/activating.

The fact that you tried some of these and it didn't work suggests your current save is glitched. You can try the usual tricks like waiting an hour or more, to see if that fixes it, but there's no guarantee that will fix it. You can also check the mods you have installed, as suggested in the comments, to see if one of those is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is how I fixed it.
Talk to your follower, tell them "I need you to do something. " point to the ground until it says "wait here"  activate. Then press tab.
This was the first thing I found when I googled my issue, hope this info helps someone else. Happy adventures, Dragonborn.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario, I just learned that if you open up the console and use it to teleport you somewhere else, it’ll work. The [console command](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#coc) is `coc` and then the cell you want to go to. I always use `coc Whiterun` because I’m too lazy to learn any others.